# Serving an entire directory tree with spray.io

Tags: scala, spray

I would like to translate [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/server.js) JS code to Scala, using `spray.io`.

How can I translate [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/server.js#L23) line below to Scala using `spray.io` ?

`app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

In other word, how can I serve an **entire directory tree** using `spray.io` ?

Comment: Spray has been deprecated in favor of akka-http.

Answer (score 1):

As comment above says Spray is deprecated. But directives are similar in akka-http. Here is what you probably need (`getFromResourceDirectory` in your case)

```
pathPrefix("docs") {
      get {
        path("swagger.json") {
          getFromResource("swagger.json", ContentTypes.`application/json`)
        } ~
          (pathEnd | pathSingleSlash) {
            redirect("docs/index.html", StatusCodes.TemporaryRedirect)
          } ~
          getFromResourceDirectory("swagger-ui")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but will this be recursive ? Will `getFromResourceDirectory("swagger-ui")` serve the entire directory tree ? For example `swagger-ui/1/2/3/4/crazy.html` ?

Comment: @jhegedus As far as i remember it will be.

Answer (score 0):

This serves files (recursively) from the directory `./web/`

```
package com.softwaremill.spray.server

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Step1Complete extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 3300) {
    get {
      path("hello") {
        complete {
          "Welcome to Amber Gold!"
        }
      }
    } ~
      pathPrefix("web" ) {
        getFromDirectory("./web/")
      }
  }

}
```